# What HTTP code to use for redirecting to a downloadable file?

Tags: http, redirect, download, http-status-codes

In my website, I've got a download page. When the user clicks on the download button, they arrive on a "thank you for downloading" page. After 2 seconds, this page redirects to the actual physical file.

So it goes a bit like that:

**Download page**: http://example.com/download

**User clicks on "Download"**: http://example.com/download/getit

**After 2 seconds, page redirects to**: http://example.com/uploads/files/file_to_download_v2.1.zip

Currently, when I redirect to the downloadable file, I use a HTTP 301 code (Moved Permanently). However I don't think this is the right code since, [according to the standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> The requested resource has been assigned **a new permanent URI** and any future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned URIs. [...] **This response is cacheable** unless indicated otherwise.

However, the page "download/getit" has not been assigned a new URI, it's just redirecting to a different resource, but its own URI hasn't changed. Also the response should not be cached since the file to download might change when a new version is released.

So what would be the right HTTP code in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return HTTP code, the page redirects **immediately**, whether you use 301 (Moved Permanently) or 302 (Found) (otherwise perfectly appropriate for your usecase). If you want to redirect **after 2 seconds**, you need to use one of:

1. `Refresh` HTTP header

   ```
   Refresh: 2; url=http://example.com/uploads/files/file_to_download_v2.1.zip
   ```
2. The same in HTML meta-equiv in the page content:

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; url=http://example.com/uploads/files/file_to_download_v2.1.zip" />
   ```
3. JavaScript, but that may not work for everybody, so I'd avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 302 Found

This way, you do not indicate that the resource has moved, just that it can be retrieved from another location.